# Best way to order boxes in a lattice bwplot by their median

Tags: r, plot, lattice, bwplot

My goal is to order the boxes in a lattice `bwplot` by their median. I know that `aggregate`, `reorder`, etc., as well as the lattice `index.cond` or `perm.cond` parameters can be used for this this purpose, but I struggle putting the pieces correctly together with `bwplot`. I would appreciate an answer that gives a clean and reusable solution, and states some details about how the parameters and functions work together in that solution - because this is what is don't fully understand right now.

This is a minimal working example of the plot without ordering:

```
bwplot(data = iris, x = Sepal.Width ~ Species)
```

To my understanding, ordering the boxes by the median could be enforced by something similar to this:

```
# notrun
bwplot(data = iris, x = Sepal.Width ~ Species | XXX, index.cond = function(x,y) reorder(x,y,median))
bwplot(data = iris, x = Sepal.Width ~ Species, perm.cond = XXX)
```

PS: the bunch of existing questions on SO related to ordering a `bwplot` (at least those I found) either investigate other details, or did not lead to a generic solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bymedian <- with(iris, reorder(Species, Sepal.Width, median))
lattice::bwplot(Sepal.Width ~ bymedian, data=iris)
```

[image]

Comment: @crayfish44 I didn't know it was that easy to implement on `lattice::bwplot` too. Not till my attempt to answer this...

Comment: @adam-quek This is a nice and clean solution. Do I get correctly that the order of boxes in `bwplot` is solely determined  from the *order of levels* in `bymedian`? This might apply to other lattice plots too, where it too might come in handy ;)

Comment: @geekoverdose from my understanding, most plot functions take the numeric levels for their plotting order.